# Can Dynamics 365 on-premise handle 5 million data?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

We have been working with four long-time clients who have been utilizing Dynamics 365. Although they are separate companies, each client has their own CRM instance running on-premises. It has been decided that the time has come to merge all four instances into a single CRM instance.(They have similar Entity data)

Currently, each organization instance contains one million accounts or customer data, including related entities. Our primary concerns regarding this merger are as follows:

1. Handling 4 million account records: Can the Dynamics CRM 365 (version 9.0) instance effectively manage this increased data volume?

We kindly request your expertise and guidance on these matters. Any insights or recommendations you can provide would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: short answer: yes. long answer: yes but you should not store millions of records inside a CRM instance

Comment: Are we talking on-prem or online ? What is your SKU ? Generally speaking 4 million of rows is nothing for either SQL or cosmos (backend storage that dynamics is using) but there are other considerations - you pay for storage. Other is how do you plan to work with those records - do you need say daily updates / sync those data outside of dataverse, etc.

Comment: @Guido Preite. This is on-premise and using SQL Enterprise version. Is that ok ? and Can handle 5 million recors?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar We are using on-premise, And SQL is enterprise version. So it will be ok to handle ?

Comment: @Anurag my answer doesn't change

Comment: You would need a high spec SQL Server, or cluster, to be able to handle multi million record entities in on-prem CRM.

Answer (score 1):

-You can use **DataFlow**, but it will be very slow.
-You can use **SSIS** and tool **KingswaySoft**, which is integrated with the MS Dynamics, it will be very fast.